# How do I write multi enter box input into .txt?

Tags: python, tkinter, text-files, easygui

### How do I make it so that "file.write(repr(fieldNames1))" writes what I input into "fieldNames1"?

```
import easygui

#Multi Enter Box
fieldNames1= ['Situation:(Example: Waiting for a friend who is late.)','Thoughts:(EXAMPLE: My friend Bob is always late!)','Emotions:(EXAMPLE: Mad & Stressed)','Behavior:(EXAMPLE: Arguing with family)']

#Write to file
file = open('Fieldnames test.txt', 'a')
file.write(repr(fieldNames1))
file.close()
```

**Makes a file called "Fieldnames test.txt" with the following text regardless of what I input into "fieldnNames1".**

> ['Situation:(Example: Waiting for a friend who is late.)',
>   'Thoughts:(EXAMPLE: My friend Bob is always late!)',
>   'Emotions:(EXAMPLE: Mad & Stressed)', 'Behavior:(EXAMPLE: Arguing with
>   family)']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that calling `repr()` on the list will create a single string from the list. What you're wanting is something like:

```
f = open('output.txt', 'a')
f.write('\n'.join(fieldNames1))
f.close()
```

The `write()` method doesn't automatically create newlines, so you have `join()` the list of strings together using a newline that's appropriate for your platform (such as `\n`). You can read more about file objects over at [the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects).

Also, I recommend using a different variable than `file`, since `file` is actually a Python function. The code will work, but you should be aware of the potential for surprises.